# Como leer un txt con python y tomar datos especificos

Tags: python

Hola tengo un archivo de texto (.txt), con datos que quiero para python para unas variables

Esto es lo que tengo en el .txt

```
Anuncio-1=875747
Banco-1=ElBanco
MontoMin-1=100
```

Me gustaría almacenar cada texto después de la igualdad en una variable cada una independientemente

Es decir el de la linea 1 "Anuncio-1=", lo que esta despues de la igualidad almacenarlo en una variable de nombre cualquiera para yo poder usar esos datos

Comment: Cuando hayas leido una línea del fichero (por ejemplo con `f.readline()` o como lo tengas implementado) puedes hacer `linea.strip().split("=")[-1]` para quitar el retorno de carro final si lo hubiera, partirla en trozos por el signo igual, y quedarte con el último trozo.

Comment: Si ese texto no tiene una cantidad de líneas fija, no se puede (ni se debe) autogenerar variables en tiempo de ejecución, sería imposible controlar el programa. Lo que puedes hacer es ir acumulando el resultado de cada línea en una sola variable tipo lista [elem1, elem2, ect...], o diccionario {id1:elem1, id2:elem2, etc...} y luego procesar los datos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes leer los datos y almacenarlos en un diccionario. La llave del diccionario es el nombre de la variable tal cual se lee desde el archivo. El valor asociado a esa llave es el mismo extraido del archivo:

```
variables = {}   # Diccionario que contendra los datos leidos.
with open("variables.txt", "r") as datos:
    for linea in datos:
        nombre, valor = linea.strip().split("=", maxsplit=1)
        variables[nombre] = valor
```

Leemos cada línea del archivo de datos y la separamos en dos partes usando `split`, con el parámetro `maxsplit` en uno, para evitar dividir algun valor que traiga un "=" dentro.

**variables.txt**

```
Anuncio-1=875747
Banco-1=ElBanco
MontoMin-1=100
Descripcion=Casos de igualdad (=) entre valores
```

con este código adicional

```
for nombre, valor in variables.items():
    print(nombre, valor)
```

produce

```
Anuncio-1 875747
Banco-1 ElBanco
MontoMin-1 100
Descripcion  Valores=anterior
```

**Observaciones**

Se supone que los nombres de variables son únicos dentro del archivo.